# Jmeter: Getting "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" error

Tags: exception, jmeter

I am trying to hit 350 users but Jmeter failing script by saying Connection timed out.

I have added following:

```
http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true in hc.parameter file

httpclient4.retrycount=1

hc.parameter.file=hc.parameter
```

Is there anything that I am missing to add on?

Answer (score 0):

This normally indicates a problem on application under test side so I would recommend checking the logs of your application for anything suspicious.

If everything seems to be fine there - check logs of your web and database servers, for instance [Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) allows 150 connections by default, [MySQL - 100](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html), etc. so you may need to identify whether you are suffering from this form of limits and what needs to be done to raise them

And finally it may be simply lack of CPU or free RAM on application under test side so next time you run your test keep an eye on baseline OS health metrics as application may respond slowly or even hang if it doesn't have any spare headroom. You can use [JMeter PerfMon plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) to integrate this form of monitoring with your load test.